# Determining the type of makefile recipe

Tags: gnu-make

I want to determine the type of recipe the user entered in the shell. However the below code always return false .

```
all clean:    
ifeq ("$@", "clean")
        echo "This is an clean recipe"
else
    echo "This is not a clean recipe."
endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MAKECMDGOALS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) to get the target:

```
all clean:
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), clean)
  @echo "This is an clean recipe"
else
  @echo "This is not a clean recipe."
endif
```

```
$ make
This is not a clean recipe.
$ make clean
This is an clean recipe
```

Comment: While this will work, the OP is going about `make` the wrong way. Have a separate rule for each target. Then refactor using subroutine/functions to reduce repeated code (I am assuming that in the real code there is commonality). When I say wrong way, I mean there are ways to write make-files that are hard to read, hard to maintain and are slow. And there are ways to make then easy to read, easy to maintain, and fast. There is a good paper "recursive make considered harmful" that is worth a read.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor  You alright. I was just wondering how I can use conditional expression in Makefile.